# Writing to a file - file not created in Visual Studio 2015 (fstream)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, fstream

I checked my current working directory

(C:\Users\Ada\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProjektPO\ProjektPO)

and tried to create a new file there but I did not work. No errors,just won't create a file.

Here's my code:

```
(#include<fstream>)



    fstream file;
    file.open("C:\Users\Ada\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProjektPO\ProjektPO\file.txt");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cass.size(); i++)
    {
        file << cass[i]->name << ";" << cass[i]->debt << endl;
    }
    file.close();
    system("pause");
```

Any tips?

Comment: Backslash is an escape character.  Use forward slash, double back-slashes, or raw strings.

Comment: I can't find a duplicate for this question.  There *has* to be one.

Comment: Backslash in quotes generally indicates a dos filepath (as opposed to unix) so should be correct strictly speaking assuming you're using windows (given it's dos 'legacy'. To use these in your string literal, you can use double backslash which 'escapes the escape e.g. "C:\\mypath"

Comment: I tried using both double backslashes and forward slash but it doesn't change anything. I also tried running the .exe file as administrator and moving the project to E:\\ drive but none of these works.

Comment: I changed the:    "fstream file;"     into      " ofstream file;"        and it works

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need to add this: 
*ios::in | ios::out*
because by default only *ios::in* is used.